# Function returns array with dates of tiles

Tags: javascript, momentjs, openlayers, layer

I have js code which returns dates of layers (Using OpenLayers and Momentjs) that stored on my PC.

As we see that the function returns all the dates between two dates from the folder (folder) with a 60-second step. But I want to return just the dates which I have files (layers) on my PC because I don't have layers for all the dates.

So what I need is a function returns an array of dates for which I have tiles only, and then add from this layer to the map depends on the entered dates

```js
function loopLayer() {
  const FromDateTime = document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
  const dateFrom = moment(FromDateTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", true);
  if (!dateFrom.isValid()) {
    log("something");
    return;
  }

  const ToDateTime = document.getElementById("todate").value;
  const dateTo = moment(ToDateTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", true);
  if (!dateTo.isValid()) {
    log("something");
    return;
  }

  let loopDate = dateFrom;
  for(let i=0; dateFrom.isSameOrBefore(dateTo) && i < 100; i++) {
    // preventing from loading thousands of layers
    loopLayerByDate(loopDate);
    loopDate = loopDate.add(60, 'seconds');

  }
}

function loopLayerByDate(dateObject) {
  const folderDate = dateObject.format("YYYY-MM-DD_HHmmss");
  const source = new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'EPSG:3854',
    // adapt url and source tile type to your setup
    url: "folder/" + folderDate + "/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png"

  });


  const layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: source,
    title: "layer"
  });
  map.addLayer(layer)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Website usually cannot read data from your local file system for security reasons. Otherwise any website could spy on your harddisk.

As you already found out, there is an exception to that rule: when you open a local HTML file, it can read file content from the harddisk. But you can't crawl through folders, so we cannot read a list of the available dates.

you have two options now:

1. add an `<input type="file" multiple>`, upload the files and use the FileAPI ([example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser) here).
2. your thing is a local html file which you open from your harddisk. You could use a trial-and-error guess approach
3. find a method to build a list of dates without the need to guess them, e.g. naming the folders with an increasing number instead of timestamps!
4. Use a server software which serves everything. The server can access the file-system and send the "front-end" the required list of dates. I won't provide an how-to here, there are tons of software-solutions and how-tos on stackoverflow and in search engines.

**Option 2, local html:**

Since you know roughly in what ranges the filenames is, you could use a brute-force approach and just query for all dates in a range and see which ones actually respond. Be aware that this approach is far from ideal and probably quite *slow*.

```
function guessValidDates(arrayOfDates){
    const validDates = [];
    arrayOfDates.forEach((date) => {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "time/" + date + "/1.png", true);
        xhttp.send();
    console.log('request returned', xhttp);
        if (xhttp.response) {
            validDates.push(date;
        }
    });
    return validDates;
}
```

Example usage:

```
// example from loopLayer function
let loopDate = dateFromObject;
const allDates = [];
for(let i=0; dateFromObject.isSameOrBefore(dateToObject) && i < 100; i++) {
  // the i counts as a failsafe, preventing us from loading billions of 
  // or whatever the pattern is for your file path
  allDates.push(loopDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD_HHmmss"));

  // step forward by X
  loopDate = loopDate.add(1, 'minutes');
}

const validDates = guessValidDates(allDates);
// now you know the valid dates and can use them. Example:
validDates.forEach(function(someDate){ 
  loopLayerByDate(someDate);
});
```

Or if you have a pattern where all layers for a single day have an increasing number, eg `"time/" + yearMontDay + '_' + increasingNumber + "/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png"`, just keep adding layers until you get a non-valid response:

```
function isValidLayer(someDateString, someNumber) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "time/" + someDateString + "_" + someNumber + "/1.png", true);
  xhttp.send();
  if (xhttp.response) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// you can now count up until you don't get a valid response anymore:

let someDateString = dateObject.format("YYYY-MM-DD_HHmmss");
let increasingNumber = 0;
while(increasingNumber < 1000) {
    // the condition is just a failsafe
    if(isValidLayer(someDateString, increasingNumber) {
      // add layer with that number to your map
      const source = new ol.source.XYZ({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        wrapX: false,
        url: "time/" + folderDate + "_" + increasingNumber + "/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png"
      });
      // TODO add layer here and so on....
    } else {
      // no more layers, stop!
      console.log('stopped after' + increasingNumber + 'layers on date ' + someDateString);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: simply name them "1", "2", "3" ... instead or some other predictable pattern.

Comment: Yeah but the user will enter two dates for ex (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) and the result is a loop of all layers from the dates folders between these two dates! So I still need their names and using momentjs

Comment: Since you are talking about "the user", you most likely won't send the user your data folder, correct? then go for option 4 (see updated answer) and provide a server! I know it's not so easy for a beginner, but there are many many tutorials on how to serve stuff over the network, e.g. with node.js

Comment: Unless you come up with a predictable pattern, you are lost then. If you can change the folder names, just use 2006-04-01_{increasingnumberhehre} or some other pattern. Or maybe the thing that generates your layer-data can also write into a text-file, so you could use the above example to fetch that text file and parse the dates from there?
There are really easy server solutions available that you just can drop into the project. E.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-http-server

Comment: I did the option 2, no debugging error, but no results! where can I in my code implement it so it works properly with my loop function?

Comment: appending MORE will not solve it, you need to replace stuff. e.g. the hours, minutes and especially the seconds. then you get a pattern where you enter a day and can fetch all data from that day by just increasing the number. The example function above takes a list of dates and checks it against your harddrive. you have to adapt the path to your content (you probably don't have a some-file.txt). What you need is a file that you _know_ it's always there, e.g. `1.png` or something If you only have binary files (images), then change `if (xhttp.responseText) {` to `if (xhttp.response) {`